# SSH passwordless connetion from Ubuntu to Win10

Tags: ssh, windows, sshd

I am trying to establish passwordless ssh connection from Ubuntu 20.04 to Win 10.
I installed new Win10 (downloaded from Microsoft site, no activated).
I downloaded openssh from git (OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.3)
I created file for my win user user/.ssh/authorized_keys and copied (with scp) my public key from ubunutu machine to it. I checked that my key exists on remote machine.

```
sshd_settings: 
PubkeyAuthentication yes 
PasswordAuthentication yes  
AuthorizedKeysFile - tried default .ssh/authorized_keys, %USERPROFILES\.ssh/authorized_keys%, with no this parameter.
```

Regular ssh connection with password works fine. Firewall was turned off.
I did same for establish ssh passwordless connection linux to linux - work fine.

I read a lot of articles: I have to create key, copy it to remote machine, reload sshd service and everything should work fine. For linux to linux it works as expected but linux to win10.

Should I have some extra settings?
Should I have extra permissions?
What did I do wrong? Could someone help me plz?

UPDATED:
I did it.
In MS [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration) said if user is admin you should place keys to another place `%programdata%/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys`
but for me it did not work. And I found row in the bottom of `sshd_setting`  about this requirements and just removed it. Now everything works fine and as expected.

Comment: Just to confirm, the problem is with OpenSSH Server *on Windows*, correct?

Comment: yes, I can not establish connection from Ubuntu to Windows.

Comment: "user/.ssh/authorized_keys and copied (with scp) my private key from ubunutu machine to it"   you need to copy public key there, not private

Comment: sorry, its mistake in explanation, I definitely copied public key

Comment: How are you connecting from Ubuntu? Are you including the key? For example: `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa koko@123.123.123.123`

Comment: I was connecting `ssh koko@123.123.123.123`. I tried to use your variant - I got asked password

Comment: Try it like this: ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null user@ip

Comment: I got `Warning: Permanently added 'ip' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.` but I also got asked password. I think it is problem in Windows. I will try ti provide more info a little late.